java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused when trying to connect to HDFS from Spark on EMR to create an ICEBERG table
I am new to spark and I'm working with a Spark job on an AWS EMR cluster using jupyter notebook. I'm trying to interact with HDFS. Specifically, I am trying to create an Apache Iceberg table. However, I am encountering the following error when executing a CREATE TABLE statement.
I have made the tables directory as mentioned in my configs using ssm
sudo su - hdfs
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /tables/iceberg_warehouse

this is my code:
cell 1:
%%configure -f
{
    "driverMemory":"30g",
    "executorMemory": "5g",
    "executorCores": 1,
    "numExecutors": 100,
    "conf": {
        "spark.jars.packages": "com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0",
        "spark.jars": "/usr/share/aws/iceberg/lib/iceberg-spark3-runtime.jar",
        "spark.submit.pyFiles": "s3://dev-datalake-us-west-2-apps/ci-artifacts/utility_files/utils.py,s3://dev-datalake-us-west-2-apps/ci-artifacts/utility_files/eventlogs_utils.py,s3://dev-datalake-us-west-2-apps/ci-artifacts/utility_files/flowlogs_utils.py",

        "spark.sql.extensions": "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions",
        "spark.sql.catalog.HdfsDataCatalog": "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog",
        "spark.sql.catalog.HdfsDataCatalog.type":"hadoop",
        "spark.sql.warehouse.dir": "hdfs://localhost:8020/tables/iceberg_warehouse",
        
        "spark.sql.catalog.HdfsDataCatalog.warehouse": "hdfs://localhost:8020/tables/iceberg_warehouse",
        "spark.sql.catalog.HdfsDataCatalog.io-impl": "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO",
        

        "spark.sql.caseSensitive": "true",
        "spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy": "LEGACY",
        "spark.sql.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite": "LEGACY",
        "spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode": "dynamic",

        "spark.driver.maxResultSize": "10g"
    }
}

cell 2:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("spark job") \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()

cell 3:
spark.sql("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HdfsDataCatalog.db.iceberg_table (
    id STRING,
    creation_date STRING,
    last_update_time STRING,
    companyid STRING
)
USING iceberg
PARTITIONED BY (companyid)
LOCATION 'hdfs://localhost:8020/tables/iceberg_warehouse'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'write.spark.fanout.enabled' = 'false',
    'write.distribution-mode' = 'none',
    'write.delete.mode' = 'copy-on-write',
    'write.update.mode' = 'copy-on-write',
    'write.merge.mode' = 'copy-on-write'
)
""")

An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o100.sql.
: org.apache.iceberg.exceptions.RuntimeIOException: Failed to refresh the table
    at org.apache.iceberg.hadoop.HadoopTableOperations.refresh(HadoopTableOperations.java:126)
    at org.apache.iceberg.hadoop.HadoopTableOperations.current(HadoopTableOperations.java:84)
    at org.apache.iceberg.BaseMetastoreCatalog.loadTable(BaseMetastoreCatalog.java:47)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2406)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2404)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2387)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:108)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalManualCache.get(LocalManualCache.java:62)
    at org.apache.iceberg.CachingCatalog.loadTable(CachingCatalog.java:166)
    at org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog.load(SparkCatalog.java:645)
    at org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog.loadTable(SparkCatalog.java:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.TableCatalog.tableExists(TableCatalog.java:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.CreateTableExec.run(CreateTableExec.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$9(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$8(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:530)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:640)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:662)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Call From ip-10-29-29-152/10.29.29.152 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;

How can I fix the Connection refused issue when Spark tries to access HDFS in an EMR environment? What steps should I take to properly configure Spark to use the correct HDFS namenode and fix this error?

I don't know anything about what you're doing but just by looking at the connectException,  I'm wondering how it's possible for 10.29.29.152 to connect to 127.0.0.1 (localhost).
